# I have a HTML form and I need to display the calculated values below the form after user clicks the submit button

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to create a prediction model using flask, where the values are entered in the input box and the result is calculated in the python file. i want to display that value or text in the same html page below the submit button. i'm new to flask and this is the first time i'm creating a web server.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set up a form to send data to your home route in your Html.

i.e.

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
        <!-- input you want to work with -->
        <input type="text" name="number">

        <!-- submit button -->
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

*Make sure the method is POST*

---

Then you need to make a flask route to accept the posted data.

Make sure it accepts both *GET* and *POST* method.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

You need to make sure to only request the form data when the method is *POST*.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    number = request.form['number']
    # do something with it
    result = number
else:
    result = None
return render_template('index.html', result=result)
```

Because:

1. You only want the browser to load the content when the method is *GET*.
2. You can't access the form in *GET* request, and thus it will cause an error.

Then, put the resulted value in a variable (in my case **result**) and pass it to the HTML file.

i.e. (Full python code)

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form['number']
    else:
        result = None
    return render_template('index.html', result=result)
```

---

Then, in your HTML file check for the variable in which your value. And if the value exists display it on the page.

i.e.

```
{% if result %}
    <p>Your no. is {{ result }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

---

I hope it helps. Comment if you have any doubt. ☺

Also might help: 
[HTTP Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pc8WdnIdXZg
 Or what you can do is to simply pass the final output generated by .py file to the html template.
Example:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    output = 2 #Let this be your output after using the prediction model
    return render_template('index.html',output=output)
```

And in index.html file you can use

```
The output is : {{output}} <!--This line will give the output from the .py file -->
```

Comment: Thank you...it really helped.